# Trigger Not Compiiling

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I have a table called xml_load. I have the primary_key set as row_id. I want the trigger to autopopulate the row_id everytime a new entry is made into the table. What am i doing wrong? (see the code below). 
I created a sequence called row_id_increase to start with 1 already.

```
create or replace trigger xml_load_trigger
before insert on xml_load
for each row
declare
begin
select row_id_increase.nextVal
into :Row_Id
from dual;
END;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `:new.row_id := row_id_increase.nextval;`

Answer (score 1):

Just prefix your column `row_id` with `:new` :

```
create or replace trigger xml_load_trigger
before insert on xml_load
for each row
declare
begin
 select row_id_increase.nextVal
   into :new.Row_Id
   from dual;
end;
/
```

Or you may assign directly as

```
:new.row_id := row_id_increase.nextVal;
```

instead of that sql.

Comment: funny thing is i found out the issue right after i posted this question. i need to be more patient. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need SELECT at all:

```
create or replace trigger xml_load_trigger
  before insert on xml_load
  for each row
begin
  :new.row_id := row_id_increase.nextval;
end;
/
```

Comment: funny thing is i found out the issue right after i posted this question. i need to be more patient. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem; I'm glad you fixed it!